# Pandas dataframe comparing with no index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading a csv file using pandas.

my dataframe consist of 3.7 million records and has two column: Date, Subscribers_ID

my dataframe data is the list of active subscribers per day.

I want to check what subscribers_id exist in day X and does not exist in day X + 1 so i can have a list of the subscribers_ID that are not inactive in day X + 1. And i want to do that for each day of the existing days.

is there any comparative function that do this or i have to create a new dataframe for each day and compare dataframes to each others. Because i have more than 75 days.

here is a sample of my data and what i want as result:

```
import pandas as pd
 
data = {'date':['22-Jan-22', '22-Jan-22', '22-Jan-22', '22-Jan-22', '23-Jan-22', '23-Jan-22', '23-Jan-22', '23-Jan-22', '23-Jan-22', '23-Jan-22', '23-Jan-22', '24-Jan-22', '24-Jan-22', '24-Jan-22', '24-Jan-22', '24-Jan-22', '24-Jan-22'], 'Subscriber_ID':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'h', 'g', 'c', 'd', 'h', 'j', 'i', 'k']}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 
print(df)
```

I want to have the following result:

-Subscribers_ID lost in 23-Jan-22 is/are: a

-Subscribers_ID lost in 24-Jan-22 is/are: e, f, b, g

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous, Does 'day X + 1' means the following calendar day or the next day in the file.

Comment: yes Day X + 1 is the next calendar day, i am sorry for not providing the details before now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple idea would be to `groupby` date and compute a `set` of the users. Then compute the reverse `diff` and `shift`. This will give you the users that left.

```
(df.groupby('date')
   ['Subscriber_ID']
   .apply(set)
   .diff(-1)
   .shift()
 )
```

Output:

```
date
22-Jan-22             NaN
23-Jan-22             {a}
24-Jan-22    {g, b, e, f}
Name: Subscriber_ID, dtype: object
```

*NB. Conveniently, if you do the same with a forward `diff`, this will give you the new users:*

```
(df.groupby('date')
   ['Subscriber_ID']
   .apply(set)
   .diff()
 )
```

Output:

```
date
22-Jan-22             NaN
23-Jan-22    {g, h, e, f}
24-Jan-22       {i, k, j}
Name: Subscriber_ID, dtype: object
```

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous, but it nevertheless seems that  'day X + 1' means the following calendar day  not the next day in the file. However, the answer corresponds to the latter case.

Comment: @hpchavaz looks like the data is continuous, but if not and the empty days must be taken into account, it is quite easy to `resample` or use a custom function in place of `diff`

Comment: @hpchavaz thank you for this solution it is working fine, the only thing that i am stuck with is after run the code you wrote and store it in a new variable the variable type is a series and the subscribers_id seems to be as one long string

Comment: The output is a Series of sets. What should be the ideal output? If you want you can convert to string using `.apply(','.join)` and export to CSV with tab delimiters using `.to_csv('filename.csv', sep='\t')`

Comment: `.apply(','.join)` isn't working i don't know why

Comment: @anto5, by the way the author of the solution is mozway

Comment: @anto5 not sure where you're stuck, maybe open a new question with sufficient details?